# MySql Generating a column of values

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL statement in MySql it is easy to create a row of values on fly by using somethig like

> SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;

this will generate a single row containing numbers from 1 to 10 but is it possible to have a single column that contains these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 10
     )
select cte.*
from cte;
```

If you have a handful of values, you can also just create them using `union all`:

```
select *
from (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
```

Comment: Thank you very much the answer is so simple and effective.